# need Regexp which leave only two dashes in a string

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

i have a string like d333-4444-555--5---5-
and want catch only two first dashes and get 333-4444-55555
if it will be first two and two in a row, two becomes one like:
d333--4444-555--5---5- goes 333-4444-55555

any advice or ready solvation

i started with
`console.log('d-45----'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))`
but it's very far from what i expect
two days on the same point

Thank you

Comment: It has to be a regex expression or you're fine with using a function to do so?

Comment: Do you need to remove the leading `d` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multiple replacements to sanitize the string.

- First replace all the 2 or more hyphens with a single hyphen as you don't know how many and where in the string you have double occurrences
- Then replace all non digits except for hyphens with an empty string, and remove the hyphens at the start and at the end of the string
- When you have the sanitized string, capture the first parts with 2 hyphens and in the last parts remove all hyphens

```js
[
  "d333-4444-555--5---5-",
  "d333--4444-555--5---5-",
  "----d333--4444-555--5---5----",
  "d333--4444",
  "d333-4444",
  "d333"
].forEach(s => {
  const res = s
    .replace(/-{2,}/g, "-")
    .replace(/[^\d-]+|^-|-$/g, "")
    .replace(/^(\d+-\d+-)(\d[\d-]*)/, (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.replace(/-/g, ""))
  console.log(res);
})
```

Another option with [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
[
  "d333-4444-555--5---5-",
  "d333--4444-555--5---5-",
  "----d333--4444-555--5---5----",
  "d333--4444",
  "d333-4444",
  "d333"
].forEach(s => {
  const res = s
    .replace(/[^\d-]+/, "")
    .split(/-+/)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .reduce((a, c, i) => i < 2 ? a + "-" + c : a + c)
  console.log(res)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A single regexp that finds all the undesirable dashes in your example is only possible in newer JS engines, which implement variable-length lookbehind assertions. Here it is:

```js
const text = "d333--4444-555--5---5-";
const re = /(?<=-+.+-+.+|-)-/g;
console.log(text.replace(re, ""));
// d333-4444-55555
```

Match each dash that has either

- two consecutive groups of hyphens somewhere before it, or
- a dash directly before it

The second condition will de-dupe consecutive dashes, leaving only a single dash in the first two groups of dashes; the first condition will remove all dashes after those first two groups.

If you also want to remove any characters that are not digits or dashes, such as the leading `d` that Kosh asked about, then this will do it:

```js
const text = "d333--4444-555--5---5-";
const re = /(?<=-+.+-+.+|-)-|[^\d-]/g;
console.log(text.replace(re, ""));
// 333-4444-55555
```

For example, Safari still does not support lookbehind assertions (haven't tried, trusting in [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)), so this might not be an appropriate solution, depending on your use case. If you need to cater to such browsers, you will need to use a more complex solution; a single regexp will not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replacer callback with a counter variable:

```js
s = 'd333---4444-55---5--5---5-'

r = s.replace(/-+/g, (count => _ => count++ < 2 ? '-' : '')(0))

console.log(r)
```